# Delayed focus when switching workspaces (lost keystrokes)

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, spaces, ventura, focus

I'm using macOS 13.6 on a 2023 MacBook Pro with an M2 chip. When I switch workspaces (using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd>), there is a delay of probably several hundred milliseconds (or maybe even a second) before a window on the new workspace acquires focus. For example, let's say I'm switching to a workspace with an open text editor. If I start typing right after hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd>, my first keystrokes will not be recognized. This is super annoying, I always have to wait a moment before doing anything when switching to another workspace.

This issue is not limited to text editors, it occurs with all keyboard input in every application I'm using. From Ubuntu, I'm used to immediately interacting with a window when switching workspaces. Any idea whether this can be fixed?

Comment: You could use Ctrl/number which is about twice as fast, but you can't get rid of the delay entirely. [I'm sure this has been asked before, but I con't find it right now.]

Comment: This is infuriating. Makes me want to switch to gnome shell again.